# Very specific issue about reduce latency between 2 photo first with flash and second without

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I work with first camera api and purpose in, I need to take two photo on one flow...

First photo with flash and second photo without. And I need to make it very fast. Exelent result between 50-100 milliseconds.

I have implemented it like this

```
public void takePicture(final boolean isWithFlash) {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            if (isWithFlash) {
                secondPhotoFinish = System.currentTimeMillis();

                presenter.saveImage(data);
                camera.release();
                presenter.goToPreviewPhoto();

                presenter.setInfo(start, firstPhotoStart, secondPhotoStart, firstPhotoFinish,
                        secondPhotoFinish);
            } else {
                firstPhotoFinish = System.currentTimeMillis();

                presenter.saveImage(data);
                camera.startPreview();
                surfaceView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        takePicture(true);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };

    if (camera != null) {
        if (!isWithFlash) {
            firstPhotoStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            camera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
        } else {
            Camera.Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
            param.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(param);

            secondPhotoStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            camera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
        }
    }
}
```

When user click `take picture` button I take regular photo and then recursive I invoked again this code, but with flash parametr...

It is works nice, but take me more than 600 milliseconds...

How I could reduce latency time?

Comment: takePicture is inherently slow. You may have better results with camera2 API, especially if you use RAW image. If the speed is more important than quality, you can use preview callback. Modern devices may deliver 1080p frames at 30fps, and some even more.

Comment: @AlexCohn nice to hear you because I know that you wide experienced in this question. Now I use camera api v1 and I use another approach I am taking picture from preview with this method `setOneShotPreviewCallback()` and eventually the best result that I got up to 200ms... but anyway I need reduce it to 4 times max time should be up to 50ms... I know that camera makes 30fps it means 33 ms per frame it means that I can take this frame with the same duration... Or not? any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but sync with flash will inevitably cause some extra delay. I doubt if that there is a sure way to make a "preview with flash", especially when you need it for speed. Maybe if you revert the sequence and start with preview without flash, and then proceed to `takePicture()` with flash, you can achieve lower delay.

Comment: If you still want to get both frames from preview flow, `setOneShotPreviewCallback()` involves some setup which may also take time. Better use preview callback with preallocated buffers, and stop after you get the second frame.

And delay all processing (including Jpeg compression) until after both frames are captured.